# Does Framer motion cause page to hard reload multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

[Update] it when I add motion to the dive it cause getserverside props issues in multiple other pages as well.

I have a page that displays a table with some information on it and when I add stagger animation to it and I reload the page, it will go crazy and cause the page to hard reload constantly. And the issue goes away as soon as I remove the motion to the rows. It also will say that the homebuyers can't be fetch from the getServerSide props

```
<tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200">
                      {homebuyerMap.map((homebuyer, index) => (
                        <motion.tr
                          key={homebuyer.id}
                          className="hover:cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-50"
                          onClick={() =>
                            void router.push(`/homebuyers/${homebuyer.id}`)
                          }
                          initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 20 }}
                          animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
                          transition={{ delay: index * 0.1 }}
                        >
                          <td className="whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-0">
                            <span className="pl-2">
                              {homebuyer.firstName} {homebuyer.lastName}
                            </span>
                          </td>
                          <td className="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
                            {homebuyer.address ? homebuyer.address : 'Pending'}
                          </td>
                          <td className="whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-3 text-sm text-gray-500">
                            {homebuyer.closeDate}
                          </td>
                          <td className="flex justify-center whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
                            <Status status={homebuyer.status} />
                          </td>
                        </motion.tr>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
```

I've removed it and it reloaded normally and I've tried to change the types of animations and sometimes it will work for a little bit but then it ends up throwing errors and spamming hard reload again.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It probably shouldn't cause that by default.

Comment: what do you not understand about it? or how can I clarify it more?

Comment: Framer motion should never cause hard reloads of the entire page, but I see you're performing your `map` inside of a JSX. That means that every time the outer component re-renders that Framer Motion is going to re-render as well.